# MySQL if exists insert id else insert into two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've made the following SQL statement and it does not work and cannot figure out how to create a functioning one. Here is what i am trying to do.

1. Check if a value exists in a players table
2. If the value exists, i want to insert ignore into a roster table
3. If the value doesnt exist, i want to insert it into the players table and insert it into the roster table

Here is what i have

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id AS plyrId FROM players WHERE email = @(:e) LIMIT 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO roster
        (date, teamId, playerId)
    VALUES
        ( (:d), (:t), plyrId )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO players 
        (status, date, first_name, last_name, email) 
    VALUES 
        ( (:s), (:d), (:f), (:l), (:e) )

    INSERT IGNORE INTO roster
        (date, teamId, playerId)
    VALUES
        ( (:d), (:t), LAST_INSERT_ID() )  //LAST_INSERT_ID() -> I want it to be pulled from the last id inserted from the players table - not sure how to accomplish this
END
```

Any help is appreciated!

ive tried another attemp without any luck either

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE email = (:e) > 0)
            INSERT IGNORE INTO roster 
                (date, teamId, playerId)
            (:d), (:t), SELECT id FROM players WHERE email =(:e)
        ELSE
        BEGIN
         .. // havent got to this part yet. it follows the same logic as the one before
        END
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your statement?

Comment: Mysql compound statements cannot be used outside of stored programs. Create a stored procedure out of your logic and call the stored procedure from your code.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT id AS plyrId FROM players WHERE email = ('john.doe@email.com')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You must use trigger on event **before insert**

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `players table` FOR EACH ROW SET
-- checking value exist or not, for each case write corresponding insert or inserts
```

Comment: do not forget use "STOP ACTION" keyword for first case

Answer (score 0):

This part of the query is highly suspect:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id AS plyrId FROM players WHERE email = @(:e) LIMIT 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO roster
        (date, teamId, playerId)
    VALUES
        ( (:d), (:t), plyrId )
----------------------^
END
```

Unless you have a variable named `plyrId`, this will fail.  Assigning an alias in a subquery does not define a variable in the outer query.

You can replace it with:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO roster(date, teamId, playerId)
    SELECT (:d), (:t), id 
    FROM players
    WHERE email = @(:e)
    LIMIT 1;
```

Or, you can change the `if` to:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT plyrdId := id FROM players WHERE email = @(:e) LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestions and i still get a 42000 error